# Swift UI - Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to check if my array contains the machine learning model output, but its giving me this weird error, and I don't understand it.

Here's my code

Image Detector class:

```
import SwiftUI

class ImageDetector: ObservableObject {
    @Published private var detector = Detector()
       
       var imageClass: String? {
           detector.results
       }
           
       // MARK: Intent(s)
       func detect(uiImage: UIImage) {
           guard let ciImage = CIImage (image: uiImage) else { return }
           detector.detect(ciImage: ciImage)
           
       }}
```

Content View:

```
    @ObservedObject var detector: ImageDetector
    
    
    let collectionArr = ["Test", "test2", "test3", "test4"]

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

            var mlOutput = detector.imageClass
        
            Group{
                
                // Outputing the information of the respective Item
                if collectionArr.contains(mlOutput) {
                    HStack{
                        Text("")
                        .font(.caption)
                        Text(mlOutput)
                            .bold()
                    }
                }
                    else {
                        HStack{
                            Text("This is not in the array")
                            .font(.caption)
                           
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure `collectionArr.contains(mlOuput)` returns an object? Semantically, it sure looks like it's going to return a `Bool`

Comment: @jnpdx It returns a Bool yes, but I want to check if the item is there only, so if true then execute the following. I'm fairly new to swift.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's going on from the code you've shared. Are you sure that detector.results returns a String? like you say in your first code sample? results implies it would be an array.

Comment: Also, please share as much *real* code as possible to reproduce the issue. Is `Group` really floating in the middle of nowhere outside a `var body: some View`? Is `mlOutput` defined inside or outside of the body?

Comment: Ok @jnpdx, I could not post more code because stack wouldn't let me. I hope that is enough. Mloutput is defined inside body

Comment: What about my question about `detector.results`. Are you sure that returns `String?`?

Comment: Yes It does return a string, optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `.contains` returns a `Bool`, you don't need to provide a binding to a variable (which is used in cases where you have a statement returning an `Optional` value).

```
//remove var mlOutput... line here
Group{
  if let mlOutput = detector.imageClass, collectionArr.contains(mlOutput) {
    HStack{
      Text("").font(.caption)
      Text(mlOutput).bold()
    }
  } else {
    HStack {
      Text("This is not in the array").font(.caption)
    } 
  }
}
```

This is assuming that `mlOuput` (which maybe is a typo for `mlOutput`?) is a `String`

Comment: Apologies @jnpdx, I should've been more explicit. mlOutput does output the results and those are strings but they come from another class. Please check my updated question.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks mate that really did it. I need to read more documentation...